Eskimo boy becomes an air force pilot
An expedition/research team goes to Antartica/Artic region. They met an Eskimo boy and his granny wants him to become a hunter. The team take him with them and he joins the air force. It seems he struggles and goes back to his native land.
I do not remember the title of that drama movie. I somewhat remember the title is The way to human heart. But I'm unable to find the details of that movie.
I watched this movie in HBO/Star movies some 15 years before.
Can you get me the name of that movie?

Map of the Human Heart from 1992:

In 1931, a chartist lands a plane in the Arctic to map unrecorded regions. He takes an Eskimo boy with tuberculosis back to civilisation where he is healed and indoctrinated in a Catholic foster home. The Eskimo meets a "half-breed" girl (father was French, mother was Indian) and they fall in love. They are separated and the Eskimo returns to the Arctic. Years later he encounters the chartist again and sends a message to his love via the chartist. He joins the air force to fight Hitler, and runs into her again, but there are obstacles that threaten his friendships and relationships.

Here's the trailer:




Exactly! Thanks for the swift and accurate answer Walt :)
